# Sorting a list of students by student id

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out how to sort a list of students by student ID. I have a list of strings, and each string contains the student's name and their ID. It looks something like this:

```
student_list = ["John,4", "Jake,1", "Alex,10"]
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
["Jake,1", "John,4", "Alex,10"]
```

My code looks like this:

```
def sort_students_by_id(student_list):
    for string in student_list:
        comma = string.find(",")+1
        student = [(string[comma:])]    

        for index in range(len(student)):
            minpos = index
            for pos in range(index+1, len(student)):
                if student[pos] < student[minpos]:
                    minpos = pos
                tmp = student[index]
                student[index] = student[minpos]
                student[minpos] = tmp
            return student_list

print(sort_students_by_id(student_list))
```

Comment: `sorted(students, key=lambda student: int(student.split(',')[1])))`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
def sort_students_by_id(student_list):
    return sorted(student_list, key=lambda s: int(s.split(',')[-1]))

 # ['Jake,1', 'John,4', 'Alex,10']
 print(sort_students_by_id(student_list))
```